# Django model group by more than 2 elements

Tags: python, sql, django

I have a table that contains userids and their score.

```
eg. userid rating
    123    1
    123    2
    456    1
    789    5
    123    1
```

What I would like to achieve is a summary table like this:

```
rating 1 : 32 ratings by 20 ppl       
       2 : 37 ratings by 15 ppl 
       etc..
```

The number of ppl should be distinct users who have given that rating.

I have gone through Django model aggregation methods and know how to use count etc. 
But I am not able to come up with something that will achieve this.

Of course i can retrieve the whole set and use a for loop in python to count but that wouldnt be efficient.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You haven't directed the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sql you're looking for is like:

```
SELECT rating, COUNT(rating) AS rc, COUNT(DISTINCT userid) FROM rating_tbl GROUP BY rating ORDER BY rc DESC;
```

You haven't provided the model, and actually it's not easy to represent the SQL in Django ORM, IMO. The easiest way is to write it directly, ref [the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
MyTable.objects.annotate(Count('rating')).order_by('rating_count').annotate(Count('user_id'))
```